# Google App Script: Listing Cell Items Based Upon Conditional Loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like my code to loop through all values listed in Column L. If the value is greater than 0, then I would like the Column K and Column A from that same row to be added to a list. This is what I have got, It's not listing my items, but it is sending the alert with the initial message.

```js
function sendEmail() {
  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Plan");
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 70; // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 12, numRows, 1);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  //email Information
  var subject = 'Current Items Needed';
  var message = 'Items needed:' + '\n';
  
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.


  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
      
     
    //expiration date information
    var quantity = row[12];  //Look at column L
    var listItem = row[11] + ' of ' + row[1] + '\n'; // 'Col K' of 'Col A'

    //checking for today
    if ( quantity > 0 ) {
      message += listItem;
        
    }
  }

  ui.alert(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The issue is the array definition and usage of indexes

1. The syntax for `getRange()` is `row, column, numRows, numColumns`, so for retrieving all cloumns from 1 to 12:

   `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 12);`
2. Mind that the first element of an array is not `1`, but `0`. Consequently column A is `row[0]` etc.
   The correct syntax is then:

```
var quantity = row[11];  //Look at column L
var listItem = row[10] + ' of ' + row[0] + '\n'; // 'Col K' of 'Col A'
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it! I'm still very new at this, so I really appreciate it.